# How do I retrieve a text file from a Virtual Private Server?

Tags: javascript, php, android, apache, sockets

we are now currently in the phase on implementing school project  with a virtual private server (VPS). However we are having problem in retrieving the data from the VPS. Our project is all about transmitting a text data from a device (which is from an android device and a remote device) to a VPS. Is there's anyway it can be called using a PHP/Javascript from the VPS? We can't use a SQL Database since our professor tells us to not use it. And is there's anyway it can be secure out?

Our professor say that we can use a socket to connect the device to the VPS and Apache to transmit the data to the web server. But I can't find a way to transmit the data using Apache

Looking for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is the web server itself. If you are able to transmit the data (generally through a HTTP POST request), then you could save it to the server using PHPs [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Then, if you need to output it, you can use the [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

E.g.

Upload.php

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data']; // Retrieve the data from the device
    file_put_contents('data.txt', $data); // Insert the data into data.txt
?>
```

Retrieve.php

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('data.txt'); // Output the ontents of data.txt
?>
```